# reply markup Telegram in webhoock ifttt

Tags: api, telegram, markup, reply, ifttt

hello sorry but I can not understand how it works. On make integromat, the function is already included in the telegram bot, while I wanted to do the same with Iftt Online I found only the guide to send message on telegram with webhoock, but I can not find anything that tells me what code to enter for reply markup S no beginner I hope you understand thank This is the text entered to send message:

????   < button > Testo del pulsante < /button >

{{EntryUrl}}/start < a href=`{{EntryUrl}}` > Leggi di più... < /a >

I do not know if it is so but I think that just add a code for the reply markup button to this code

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot0000000/sendMessage?chat_id=@prova&text=<b>{{EntryTitle}}<b>
<br>
{{EntryContent}}
<br>
  {{EntryUrl}}
```